# Getting controller and action from inside a message handler (NOT a controller)?

Tags: routes, handler, message

How do you extract the controller and action name from a request, in a message handler in web api 2, framework 4.5? For example, this gets the full url: `
                Uri url = request.RequestUri; 
                string originalUrl = url.OriginalString;

Am using attribute routing`

Answer (score 3):

```
var config = request.GetConfiguration();
var routeData = config.Routes.GetRouteData(request);
var controllerContext = new HttpControllerContext(config, routeData, request);

request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpRouteDataKey] = routeData;
controllerContext.RouteData = routeData;

// get controller type
var controllerDescriptor = new DefaultHttpControllerSelector(config).SelectController(request);
var controllerName = controllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
controllerContext.ControllerDescriptor = controllerDescriptor;

// get action name
var actionMapping = new ApiControllerActionSelector().SelectAction(controllerContext);
var actionName = actionMapping.ActionName;
```

All the credit goes to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/joepour/5428971).